# Adding a background-image on an <img> itself?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Is it possible to add a `background-image` on an `<img>` tag? **I cannot create a** `<div>` around it for now (due to other restraints). I'm wondering if it's possible on just the `<img>` tag. Thanks.

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cieau.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/eau_nature.jpg">
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with both an `src` and a `css` bg image on the `img` tag?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Luke_ Client asked if its possible to get a logo in the bottom right corner ontop of certain images (product images)

Comment: You can use relative positioning but you should definitily use 2 seperate image elements and put them ontop of eachother

Comment: Would be better to apply the images (or at least the rear image) as a background on a structural element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use padding and add the image there:

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  padding:0 0 50px 0;
  background: url('https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png') bottom right/auto 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cieau.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/eau_nature.jpg">
```

Like below by considering multiple backgrounds and by keeping only the padding area:

```css
img {
  width: 0;
  height:0;
  padding:300px 500px 0 0;
  background: 
    url('https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png') bottom right/auto 50px,
    url(https://www.cieau.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/eau_nature.jpg) center/cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cieau.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/eau_nature.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont see the nature image anymore now

Comment: @Panic added another idea too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible - but the img would need some transparency for you to see the background image of course.

This snippet is the same as yours but with the actual img src removed and a width and height put on the img element so it has some dimensions, since it isn't in this case picking them up from the img itself. You can see the StackOverflow logo emerging from underneath.

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<img src="" width=200 height=200>
```